# LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, so bear with me. When I compile a I get this error.
Included are both cpp and header file. This is the error that I'm getting:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 12_6, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\How to program\ch12_6\12_6\Debug\12_6.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

CommissionEmployee.h

```
#ifndef COMMISSION_H
#define COMMISSION_H

#include <string> // C++ standard string class
using namespace std;

class CommissionEmployee
{
public:
   CommissionEmployee( const string &, const string &, const string &, 
      double = 0.0, double = 0.0 );

   void setFirstName( const string & ); // set first name
   string getFirstName() const; // return first name

   void setLastName( const string & ); // set last name
   string getLastName() const; // return last name

   void setSocialSecurityNumber( const string & ); // set SSN
   string getSocialSecurityNumber() const; // return SSN

   void setGrossSales( double ); // set gross sales amount
   double getGrossSales() const; // return gross sales amount

   void setCommissionRate( double ); // set commission rate (percentage)
   double getCommissionRate() const; // return commission rate

   double earnings() const; // calculate earnings
   void print() const; // print CommissionEmployee object
private:
   string firstName;
   string lastName;
   string socialSecurityNumber;
   double grossSales; // gross weekly sales
   double commissionRate; // commission percentage
}; // end class CommissionEmployee

#endif
```

CommissionEmployee.cpp

Comment: Show your main. BTW you only include the header.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have defined a main function. A program needs to have a main function. The linker expects that and if it is not defined, then it chokes. The main function is the entry point for your program and without it, the program cannot start.